# how to hide a bootstrap modal using React JSX

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am learning react and I want to close a bootstrap modal after a 'Post' callback

So, in the below code I want to hide the modal in the 'hideModal' method when `onClick={() => postDocument.callApi(this.state.document, this.hideModal)}` calls back.

How can I do this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import postDocument from "./../rest/PostDocument";
import fetchPersons from "./../rest/FetchPersons";
import PersonList from "./../components/PersonList";
import ShowDatePicker from "./../components/ShowDatePicker";
import moment from "moment";

class SaveDocument extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    document: {
      documentDate: moment(),
      personFrom: {
        id: ""
      },
      personTo: {
        id: ""
      },
      comments: ""
    }
  };

  hideModal = hideModalInfo => {
    // How do I hide the modal here!
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="basicExampleModal"
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                Save document
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => postDocument.callApi(this.state.document, this.hideModal)}
              >
                Save changes
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SaveDocument;
```

Answer (score 3):

##### A different approach is to simulate a .click() on the close button,

```
...
const closeRef = useRef();
...
<button
  type="button"
  className="close"
  data-dismiss="modal"
  aria-label="Close"
  ref={useRef}
>
...
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-primary"
  onClick={() => {closeRef.current.click()}}
>
Save changes
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import jquery and call Bootstrap's `modal("hide")` method...

```
import $ from "jquery";

...

hideModal = hideModalInfo => {
  $("#myModal").modal("hide");
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ykkvl7547j

Answer (score 0):

you should bind that method. onClick={this.handleClick}

```
class SaveDocument extends Component {

  constructor(props){
       super(props);
       state = { ... }
       //This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
       this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
     return (<button
            type="button"
            onClick={this.hideModal)}
          >)
  }

};
```

[more info about bindings](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

Also, i have a basic example working:

https://codepen.io/ene_salinas/pen/yRGMpG

```
      ReactModal.setAppElement('#main');

      class ExampleApp extends React.Component {
        constructor () {
          super();
          this.state = {
            showModal: false
          };

          this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
          this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
        }

        handleOpenModal () {
          this.setState({ showModal: true });
        }

        handleCloseModal () {
          this.setState({ showModal: false });
        }

        render () {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>Trigger Modal</button>
              <ReactModal 
                 isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                 contentLabel="onRequestClose Example"
                 onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
                 className="Modal"
                 overlayClassName="Overlay"
              >
                <p>Modal text!</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
              </ReactModal>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      const props = {};

      ReactDOM.render(<ExampleApp {...props} />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

In your code (if you have jquery):

```
constructor(){
   this.state = { hideModal = true }
}


hideModal() {
  this.state.hideModal = true
  //i dont recommend, i prefer use the state
   $("#modal").hide()
};

showModal() {
  this.state.hideModal = false
  //i dont recommend, i prefer use the state
  $("#modal").show()
};

render(){
   <button value="open modal" onClick={showModal} />
   //div modal
   <div class={this.state.hideModal ? 'hide' : 'show'}>
      <button value="close modal" onClick={hideModal} /> 
   </div>

}
```

Comment: but you are using ReactModal right?? I am using basic bootstrap. Is there a way of closing it when it's a bootstrap modal?

Comment: when you press close button, you must change the state, where the state must be associated with style or class display:none

Comment: close button works already with the bootstrap  data-dismiss="modal". I want to close it in a callback ; i.e. jsx method

Comment: just remove data-dismiss attribute

Comment: @YasinMustafa please check out, i did edit the answer

Comment: i want to close on 'close button' click -> already works out of the box!!! I also want to close on callback using JSX... that is my question.

Comment: adding hide class doesnt close it properly. I need to do something like in jquery ${#basicExampleModal).hide() or call data-dismiss on the modal... but dont know how to in JSX

Comment: if you have jquery in your project do it, $("#modal").hide() , important is that method is binding in constructor as above example.

Answer (score -1):

bootstarp has jquery based functions so

1.if you use jquery here use this one

```
$("#basicExampleModal").modal("hide");
```

2.Or we can use **data-dismiss="modal"** to that button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```